# Теряются строки при чтении из файла

Tags: java, filestream

Здравствуйте.Хочу прочитать строки из файла , в файле 6177 строк.Пи чтении теряю ровно 60 строк.Это где то из середины.Первые и последние выходят.

```
public class Data {

    public static int countStr []= new int[114];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //заполняю countStr[] числами.Числа  разные.
        initItem();

        File f = new File("text.txt");    

        FileReader fR = new FileReader(f);

        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fR);

        int cnt =0;

        for(int i =0 ;i <countStr.length;i++){

              cnt +=1;
                if(i!=cnt&&cnt<114){

                     for(int k =0;k<countStr[cnt];k++){
                      //Если в ячейке массива напр.7 , то вывожу семь строк.
                              System.out.println(bf.readLine());
                      }
                 }else{
                      System.out.println("массив закончился");
                 }


        }


        fR.close();
        bf.close();
```

Comment: Пока непонятно как выводятся остальные 6117 строк, если вы перебираете не строки файла, а делаете цикл по массиву из 114 элементов. Причем даже bf5 вместо bf написан. Видимо это не весь код

Comment: да.тут чуть форматировал.в массиве чтобы знать сколько строк выводить.

Comment: Я не знаю вашей задачи и целей, но обычно чтение из BufferedReader  пишут так: `String sCurrentLine;

   while ((sCurrentLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
   }`. А что за магия с двумя циклами мне всё равно не ясно

Comment: Мне же это не подходит..

Comment: Хотел попробовать , но потом вспомнил что я знаю сколько раз должен пробежаться.

Comment: Почему вам не подходит чтение файла нормальным чпособом? :)

Comment: строки нужно забить в массивы.каждую строку на одну ячейку.Тексты на 4.5 мб.

Comment: Так, и чем это мешает? (кстати можно использовать List)

Comment: Пожалуй так и сделаю.

Comment: Используйте коллекцию вместо массива и нормальный цикл, как вам тут показали. Тогда ваша программа не будет зависить от того, сколько строк в файле. Указывать количество строк для каждого файла - вообще не вариант.